I'm getting a build error in my Spring Boot application when trying to build on new machine
When trying to compile my Spring Boot application I get the following. It works fine on the original machine I started building this on but now I'm on a new machine and get this error.
I copied over all my applications and props over and not really seeing why it is not compiling any more.
WARN 66721 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Failed to initialize dependency 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' of LoadTimeWeaverAware bean 'entityManagerFactory': Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2024-12-07T16:31:34.911-05:00  INFO 66721 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-12-07T16:31:34.916-05:00  INFO 66721 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-12-07T16:31:34.925-05:00 ERROR 66721 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
        If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
        If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

MY POM.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>f1-dashboard</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>f1-dashboard</name>
    <description>Formula 1 Dashboard</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.23.1-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.6.0</version> <!-- Ensure you have the correct version -->
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

My application.properties:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/f1dashboard
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update


You are using com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver (MySQL) for the driver class but jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/f1dashboard (Postgres) for the DB URL. I assume this isn't intentional.

What exactly are you executing to get the given error?

im just running: mvn spring-boot:run, and yes that(mySQL) was a mistake that was removed.

When you say application.prop, do you mean that is exactly the file name? Spring Boot looks for a file named application.properties specifically, so application.prop will be ignored. Also, your last property in that file is not correct. Properties are of the form key=value, no :. Also, driver-class-name is not a recognized by default. Do you mean spring.datasource.driver-class-name?

yes its application.properties just abbreviated for the post, and as for the last property in the it was deleted. was added by accident thanks!

What's your project structure like, hopefully the application.properties file is in the classpath in other words by convention in the src/main/resources directory

I am suspect to 1. java version in new machine 2. system variables(env in linux) 3. application.properties path 4. IDE files like .ide directory and .impl files and 5. maven version. Please share your project structure (if possible) and your environments

@SatrajitA thank you, my app.props was outside my resources folder for some reason. that fixed the issue!
